# How can I determine if ToString method is returning the object type name versus an actual value?

Tags: .net, caching, tostring

I intend to us the ToString() method for creating a cache key. This cache will be used to cache method level invocations and the key will be constructed by using the parameters names and corresponding values. Since this caching is going to be built for a large library I do not have the ability to ensure that every method has only value type parameters or all classes implement serialization. I need to determine at run time that the call to ToString is returning an actual value versus the type name so that that method invocation can be disallowed from participation in the caching.

for Instance, consider the following method and its invocation

```
AccountDetails GetDetails(int groupId, Account account)
{
    var ac1 = new Account( accountId = 123 };
    var ac2 = new Account( accountId = 555 };
    var return1 = GetDetails(15, ac1);
    var return2 = GetDetails(15, ac2);
}
```

In this case i would construct cache key as "groupId=15+account=namespace.Account" causing an incorrect collision. How do i detect at runtime that my call to account.GetString() is going to return a type name?

Comment: Why would you use `ToString` for caching purposes? That's not what it's there for. Why don't you use `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, which are generally much more appropriate for caching - or create your own interface to be implemented...

Comment: Yep, it seems absolutely insane to want to solve the Halting problem to determine what an arbitrary method invocation will return, when `GetHashCode` has already been built and defined to provide a good level of distinction between instances.

Comment: Agreed, ToString() is just for that, to provide a human-readable string from an object.  If you really want to use the string you mentioned as a cache key, then I would add some interface `ICacheable` that provides a `string GetCacheKey()`.  But isn't using a string for your key going to be inefficient? Depending on how you cache, `GetHashCode` will end up being called on your string anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet - It occurs to me that this situation is similar to output caching for a Http Request. The exact object is not important, but the value of the object is important. I'm working on enterprise software, with a massive code base. We understand that we will not be able to cache the output of every single boundary call, but for methods that accept only value parameters it is possible by building up the cache key from parameter name and value. Which is why the ToString() and opt out reference types that do not provide be a suitable value.

Comment: @zync: It sounds like `GetHashCode` and `Equals` are *exactly* what you should be using, not the string representation. You could only accept types which implement `IEquatable<T>` for example. That will give a *much* better experience than using ToString, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Ok. That's what I was looking for. IEquatable solves the issue. Thanks !

Comment: @zync: Okay, will add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using strings for general cache keys. It's really not what `ToString` was designed for. Instead, you should be using `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to check for equality. Of course, like `ToString`, every object has `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods... but fortunately, there's the [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface which provides a *much* stronger signal that a type was really *designed* for equality.

So for any given type `X`, just check whether that type implements `IEquatable<X>`. If it does, it should be reasonable to use as a cache key. If you're writing a generic method, you can enforce this:

```
void Foo<T>(T key, /* other parameters */) where T : IEquatable<T>
```

Comment: So in theory this works, but for my specific scenario, I need to get the hash code from a passed in "object". The problem is that the only way I can seem to determine whether the passed in object implements IEquatable is by executing target.GetType().GetInterface(typeof(IEquatable<>).FullName). This leads to reflection and kills performance.

Comment: @zync: Unfortunately you haven't given us enough context to help you much - we don't know whether you've got a generic method etc. You could easily keep a cache by type, although you shouldn't need to use the *name* at all - use `typeof(IEquatable<>).MakeGenericType(target.GetType())` and then check whether the type implements that specific interface.

Comment: Sorry about that(Its 3 am here). Nope - I don't have a generic function. I'm intercepting functions using unity interception. What i receive is information about the method intercepted and a collection of paramter "object"s. I need to figure if these objects can be candidates for GetHashCode + Equals. I'll try what you mentioned; another option seems to be target.GetType().GetInterfaces() and then string compare to typeof(IEquatable<>).FullName. But your suggestions seems more reliable than a string compare on type names.

Comment: @zync: It should be faster, too :) You can use `Type.IsAssignableTo` as one way of checking for interface implementation (there are various others). But caching from type to "is this valid" may well be worth doing.

Comment: huh. yep. that works. Will check on performance. Luckily this is going to run on the server side :)

Comment: finally - 
typeof(IEquatable<>).MakeGenericType(target.GetType()).IsAssignableFrom( target.GetType())

Answer (score 0):

I can't know what implementation is in the "ToString" method (for all you know, someone overloaded the "ToString" in "Object" but implemented it the same way as it's implemented in "Object").

You can't use ToString as a sort of hash for an object. Think about two logically different objects like two "Student" objects with the same full name and different IDs (or some non-ascii value like picture). You need to use a real Hash - See "GetHashCode".

If "GetHashCode" isn't an option, we're going to need more information (like "why")

Comment: Not an answer (more a comment, along the same lines of the existing ones)

Comment: Note that `GetHashCode` shouldn't be used *on its own*. Unlike cryptographic hashes, hash codes from objects can entirely reasonably have collisions in easy-to-create situations. `GetHashCode` should be used as the first step in checking for equality, not as a final step.